# how to avoid duplicate selection of items in dropdown which is in gridview using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have dropdown (select in html ) in gridview (table in html) .This grid view has multiple rows. My objective is not to allow the user to select the same items in dropdown list .

For example if a user select newyork

asigning rooms

```
usernamedropdown        roomnumber
john                       1
john  (this  is wrong)     2
```

I want to handle onchange of each dropdown and loop through all the values in the grid and if any dropdown value matches with the selected value through error.

what i tried

```
<asp:Gridview id="grdtest" runat="server">

<asp:dropwnlist id="testid"  runat="server" onchange =" checkforvalue(this);">

</asp:Gridview>
```

**JS**

```
function checkforvalue()
{

var valuetocheck= $(testid).selectedvalue;


i am stuck here 

// loop through all rows in gridview\table and find all the value of dropdown and test .


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through your grid rows and target the correct column/cell.

```
$('#grdtest tr').each(function(i){
   if($(this).find('td').eq(0).text() == valuetocheck){ 
       /* .eq(column index [0 is first]) - I am assuming here
          that your values are stored as strings in the table and 
          using .text() to pluck them out */
       /* duplicate value is present */
   } 
});
```